# How to use variable inside execute select statement where clause without getting error on column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

**I am having some trouble with running stored procedure in which select statement is throwing error on column name?**

Below stored procedure creates data inside a loop from the result of select statement. The problem is that where clause `WHERE r.report_status = IN_CONSIDERATION` THROWING EXCEPTION INDICATING THAT IN_CONSIDERATION is not a column, yes indeed it is not a column and it should not be but why it is not working? any clues? really appreciated. I will post exception below

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.field_validations2(
  )
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
   cust_rec RECORD;
    new_signature_id bigint;
   inconsideration varchar;
BEGIN
    inconsideration := 'IN_CONSIDERATION';
    FOR cust_rec IN
        EXECUTE format('SELECT l.* FROM public.report_attached_person_many_to_many l INNER JOIN public.report r ON l.report_id = r.id WHERE r.report_status=%I', inconsideration)
    LOOP
  INSERT INTO public.report_signature(
    id, active, created, created_by, deleted, modified, modified_by, comment, status, type, staff, is_finished)
  VALUES (nextval('hibernate_sequence'),'true','1561713543512', '123', 'false', '1561713543512', '123', 'should be deleted after testing', '0', '1' , cust_rec.staff_id , 'false')
  RETURNING new_signature_id;
  INSERT INTO public.report_required_signatures_many_to_many(
      report_id, signature_id)
      VALUES (cust_rec.report_id, new_signature_id);
    END LOOP;
END
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.field_validations2()
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

Exception I am getting:

```
    ERROR:  column "IN_CONSIDERATION" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ort r ON l.report_id = r.id WHERE r.report_status="IN_CONSID...
                                                             ^
QUERY:  SELECT l.* FROM public.report_attached_person_many_to_many l INNER JOIN public.report r ON l.report_id = r.id WHERE r.report_status="IN_CONSIDERATION"
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function field_validations2() line 8 at FOR over EXECUTE statement
SQL state: 42703
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have single quotes around this?  r.report_status="IN_CONSIDERATION"

Comment: You mean just after = "IN_CONSIDERATION" ? I have tried this select statement it is working on query tool but inside format() it is not @B.Seberle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use %L instead of %I in your format string

```
EXECUTE format('SELECT l.* FROM public.report_attached_person_many_to_many l INNER JOIN public.report r ON l.report_id = r.id WHERE r.report_status=%L', inconsideration)
```

**EDIT**

Why do you use execute for your select query? Why not just

```
FOR cust_rec IN (
  SELECT l.*
  FROM public.report_attached_person_many_to_many l
    INNER JOIN public.report r ON l.report_id = r.id
   WHERE r.report_status = inconsideration)
LOOP
```

Comment: ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function field_validations2() line 11 at SQL statement
SQL state: 42601 when I run this procedure?

Comment: See [Manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) section 9.4.1. format.

Comment: I have found a solution. Returning id into your variable name was giving the conflict Thank you guys